# Excel Power Query to pivot Rent Roll with lease charges

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a sample truncated rent roll below (actual is hundreds of lines long with different combinations of lease codes, vacancies, moveouts).  There is some randomness to the data as there are vacancies which make "moveIn, LeaseEnd, moveOut" fields blank and sometimes there are moveOuts.

I would like to pivot the leaseCodes to separate columns as seen in the second image.

**Is it possible to do this in power query without custom code**?  My initial thoughts were to do fill down on all of the fields except lease code and amount and then pivot the leaseCode Column with the Amount Column.  But as you can see, I won't be able to do this because the date columns are sometimes blank due to vacancies or filled with moveouts.

Would really appreciate anyone's help on best way to navigate this.

Thank you,

[image: Raw data]

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: I'd actually remove the "leaseCode" column in 2nd image as there's no need for it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Table1 by selecting data and using Data...From Table/Range [x] including headers. Right click unit column and Fill...Down...  Select [unit, leaseCode, Amount] columns, right-click RemoveOtherColumns.  Use the drop-box next to LeaseCode column header and uncheck (null) to get rid of those rows.  Select leaseCode column then Transform...Pivot Column... and for value column use Amount. Do  File ... Close and Load To ..... Only Create Connection.   You should get something similar to this code (edited to replace datetime with date).  Make sure this query is named Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"unit", Int64.Type}, {"floorplan", type any}, {"unitArea", Int64.Type}, {"resident", type text}, {"tenant", type text}, {"marketRent", Int64.Type}, {"leaseCode", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"residentDeposit", Int64.Type}, {"otherDeposit", Int64.Type}, {"moveIn", type date}, {"leaseEnd", type date}, {"moveOut", type date}, {"balance", type any}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"unit"}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filled Down",{"unit", "leaseCode", "Amount"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ([leaseCode] <> null)),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[leaseCode]), "leaseCode", "Amount", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Back in normal excel, show Queries dialog box (if not already open) with Data...Queries and Connections... right click Table1 query and choose Duplicate. Delete every step after step 2 in the Applied Steps tab off to the right by right clicking step called "Filled Down" and using Delete until end. Use the drop-box next to [unit] column header and uncheck (null) to get rid of those rows. Select the [leaseCode, Amount] columns and right click Remove Columns to get rid of those two.   Home...Merge Queries... and in the bottom drop down choose Table1 we created before.  Click unit column in top section and then unit column in bottom section to link them.  Join kind is left outer, the default. Hit OK.  Click the double arrow atop the new column, uncheck unit, uncheck use original column name as prefix, then hit OK. Resort columns as needed. Change types as needed Close and load to table.  Should generate code similar to

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"unit", Int64.Type}, {"floorplan", type any}, {"unitArea", Int64.Type}, {"resident", type text}, {"tenant", type text}, {"marketRent", Int64.Type}, {"leaseCode", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"residentDeposit", Int64.Type}, {"otherDeposit", Int64.Type}, {"moveIn", type date}, {"leaseEnd", type date}, {"moveOut", type date}, {"balance", type any}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([unit] <> null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"leaseCode", "Amount"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns",{"unit"},Table1,{"unit"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"mta", "watr", "Total", "garg"}, {"mta", "watr", "Total", "garg"})
in #"Expanded Table1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing.  Now that this is done, what is the best way to save this procedure to reapply to files all the time?

Comment: Just paste in an updated data table on the worksheet and and Data ... Refresh All...

Answer (score -1):

In the Query Editor, highlight the lease code and amount  columns and then pivot them (from the Transform tab on the Query Editor ribbon).